# Android: Is it possible to share a GoogleApiClient between activities and services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, singleton-methods

Do every activity and service have to create their own GoogleApiClient and manage it with their onPause, onStop and connectivity issues? Is it possible to make an app client?

What I'm doing now is to copy and paste the same code in every activity or service. It works but I wonder if I am misunderstanding.

here is the [code](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible you separate the `GoogleApiClient` concern from both `Activity` and `Services`, turning it into an observable model as shown in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734567/separating-the-concerns-of-activity-and-googleapiclient), allowing one or many classes have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is make a BaseActivity that handles all the googleApiClient Logic, and extend all your activities from that BaseActivity.